# Httprest performance improvement

Tags: java, rest

I am doing a HTTPRest post call to send the data to a third party,
my data is in the order of 3 to 10 million and i can send only one record per request along with  username and password for authentication as specified by third party

sample code that i am using is

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  try {

    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(
        "http://localhost:8080/RESTfulExample/json/product/post");

    StringEntity input = new StringEntity("{\"qty\":100,\"name\":\"iPad 4\"}");
    input.setContentType("application/json");
    postRequest.setEntity(input);

    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);

    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 201) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
            + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    }

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader((response.getEntity().getContent())));

    String output;
    System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(output);
    }



  } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

  } catch (IOException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

  }

}
```

for each request it is taking around 6 sec and if i calculate for 10 million records it will take hours  , can some one please suggest me are the any ways to improve the performance ??

thanks in advance 
Sunny

Answer (score 1):

First, if one request takes 6 seconds, 10 million records will take 115 days. So you should reduce the response time from 6 seconds to several hundred of milliseconds first before you  use some multithread tech to increase performance from cilent side.

Answer (score 1):

Use [This code](http://yogeshmprajapati.blogspot.in/2011/12/login-to-fb-from-java.html)
this will increase performance while calling REST 
because this uses classs of Jax api like WebResource and so on....

Comment: Dear Yogesh, thank you very much for response , i have included jercy 1.4 .jar but i am getting compilation error . will it work with 1.5 ??? i am getting version errors